# Python code stops updating Mysql database randomly

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to learn Python by building myself a trading bot kind of application. This also uses a mysql database. I have a class for handling all database operations. The class is structured like so:

```
class BotDB:
 def __init__(self, dbUsername, dbPassword):
        print("Initializing database.")
        self.__dbUsername = dbUsername
        self.__dbPassword = dbPassword

    # Function to connect to db.
    def __connectToDatabase(self):
        print("Connecting to database")
        try:
            self.__botDB = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                port=3306,
                user=self.__dbUsername,
                password=self.__dbPassword
            )
            self.__botDBCursor = self.__botDB.cursor(buffered=True)
            return True
        except Exception as e:
            print("Something went wrong in connecting to database.")
            print(e)
            return False
```

The self.__botDBCursor and self.__botDB get used in all different functions within BotDB class. There are functions that update a specific table within the database quite frequently. I find that the database stops being updated after a time. Quite randomly too and without errors. I have gone through some of the threads here and

- I am calling `commit` on the update transactions.

My questions:

- A lot of the other threads point out that it is important to close the connections once done. But I am re-using the object once created. Do I still need to close and re-open the connections?
- Are there better ways of diagnosing or handling this? Like ORMs for Python that can manage connections ?

Comment: that are two quewstion, bur what error do you get exactly

Comment: none. i get no error. the update to the table stops quite randomly. even now the program is running, the update query seems to be running with no errors but i am not seeing anything in the table.

Comment: then add the code for updateing as well, there could be tiomeouts, see in the mysql error log if there are anomalies

Comment: Also, I hope a SINGLE connection is not used in parallel in multiple requests/threads.  That must never happen.  A connection should be used only in one thread at a time. If another thread requires a connection, it should be given a separate connection. So, a proper Connection Pooling mechanism with 'free' and 'in-use' list of connections should be implemented. Same connection can be used in another thread only if the first thread has released it and not actively using it. Just one connection for all the activities won't work.